# 1С встроенный почтовый клиент

Tags: 1с

**1С:Предприятие 8.2 (8.2.13.219) нетиповая конфигурация**

Добрый день!

Товарищи (которые нам совсем не товарищи), разрабатывающие нашу ЦРМ, в свое время вырезали встроенный почтовый клиент, и *орудиментировали* (другие недослова в голову не идут) другие вкусняшки. Обращаться к ним по поводу возвращения вырезанных элементов, к сожалению, бесполезно.

Поэтому подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти модули почтового клиента, или какие-то заготовки, или чтиво по этому делу для этой версии 1с предприятия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас используется новый формат работы 1С - так называемые Управляемые формы. То библиотека стандартных подсистем вам в помощь(Есть на сайте технической поддержки. Так же могу выслать на почту). Там есть почтовый клиент от 1С. 
Если же вы используете старый формат работы 1С. то смотрите любую типовую конфу - УТ или УПП.

Comment: вышлите, пожалуйста

Comment: Скинь адрес куда отправлять на AOkipny[ГАВ]nastroy-ka.ru